# Laptop Broken and Removed screen. HDMI and VGA not working

Tags: display, hdmi, vga

I have a Lenovo G570 laptop. It's screen was broken so I removed it. After which, I tried connecting it to another monitor using VGA and HDMI. However, it's not displaying anything. 
I cannot seem to hear any beeps or anything during boot-up.
Does the HDMI or VGA require my screen to be intact for it to function?

Comment: You're display can be turned off and still have it work on another monitor (projector only for instance). You might have broken something graphics based while removing the screen. I wonder why you needed to remove the broken screen if you where going to then use an external one.

Comment: Actually, that laptop's not mine. it was my in-law's. The laptop's broken more than a year ago. 'twas only now that we decided to use an external monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its broken GPU (Graphic card). Before you unmounted screen was it broken and black, or was it lighting up ? Did you see anything on it? 
The cord from Laptop Panel is not related with gpu external port. But if both dont work then its a larger problem - probably dead gpu and not monitor.

Comment: 'twas not working at all. It's not displaying anything nor giving beeps before boot up...

Comment: Does it boot, or the hdd led flashes?